# How to handle projections in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb, projection

Given domain model...

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

... I want to project results of a select query to this view model:

```
public class EntityViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the following query:

```
var viewModel = (from entity in _documentSession.Query<Entity>()
                select new EntityViewModel
                            {
                                Id = entity.Id,
                                CategoryTitle = entity.Category.Title
                            }.ToList();
```

The result of this is only partially correct: the `Id` is set, the `CategoryTitle` is not. I understand this behaviour is *by design*, but I suspect there is an API to handle this scenario.

How should such a projection be handled in RavenDB?

**Update:** I am using build 1.0.573 in embedded mode.

**Updated 2:** I have forked RavenDB repository, added a failing test to demonstrate this behaviour and created a [pull request (#444)](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/pull/444). Will post more info as I find out.

Comment: What build are you using? This should actually work

Comment: @AyendeRahien Build 1.0.573 in embedded mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is actually a bug. [See pull request #444 for more information](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/pull/444#issuecomment-3597149).

<strike>I will update this answer when this is fixed in a stable release.</strike>

Fixed in the current stable release.